# Optimizing iOS apps for certain situations

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

When the user turns on internet sharing the black bar on top turns a blue colour and becomes wider and this causes the User interface to drop down a little bit and cause some problems, due to the face it now looks strange because items have been pushed down and are potentially cut off at the bottom. Is there any way to deal with this situation? and if so are there any tutorials out there to help with it? I've been searching but haven't come up with anything yet!

Comment: @mikeweller's answer is helpful, but Apple's recommendation for this issue is Auto Layout. Attempts to avoid Auto Layout will tend to run into more and more problems as more of iOS relies on your using it. This trend is only increasing.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` notifications which will tell you the new size of the status bar. You can use this to adjust your UI if need be. Avoid hard coding anything (e.g. 40pt) and instead get the new status bar frame from the notification.

If you just need the height, you can pull that out easily. If you need to do anything more complicated with the status bar frame, you'll have to convert it from screen coordinates to your own view's coordinate system (e.g. if you have a full screen layout view controller and need to lay things out underneath it):

```
- (void)statusBarFrameWillChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSValue *rectValue = notification.userInfo[UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey];

    CGRect statusBarFrame = [rectValue CGRectValue];

    // if you just need the height, you can stop here

    // otherwise convert the frame to our view's coordinate system
    UIWindow *targetWindow = self.view.window;
    // fromWindow:nil here converts from screen coordinates to the window
    CGRect statusBarFrameWindowCoords = [targetWindow convertRect:statusBarFrame
                                                       fromWindow:nil];
    CGRect frameRelativeToOurView = [self.view convertRect:statusBarFrameWindowCoords
                                                  fromView:targetWindow];

    // ...
}
```

Converting the coordinates is going to be especially important in iOS 7 where all view controllers have full screen layout by default.

Comment: so do i have to add this to every view i need to change the items in?